# The tailwind menu in mobile should be closed when clicked outside

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I made the Navbar using Tailwind and Apline. The toggle menu does not close when clicking outside on mobile.

[image]

```
<nav
    class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between w-full py-2 px-4 text-xl text-gray-700 navbar-bg fixed z-20 top-0">
  <div>
      <a href="#">
        <img class="w-1/2"
                src="./assets/images/whers-logo-2021_mobile2.png">
          <g
            id="Group_330"
            data-name="Group 330"
            transform="translate(-251.1 457.654)"
          >
            <g
              id="Group_329"
              data-name="Group 329"
              transform="translate(251.1 -457.654)"
            >
              <path
                id="Path_121"
                data-name="Path 121"
                d="M257.887-454.034a12.084,12.084,0,0,1,3.505-3.62,11.811,11.811,0,0,1,3.46,3.549,17.887,17.887,0,0,1,3.362,11.216c.73.589,1.482,1.154,2.2,1.754a3.969,3.969,0,0,1,1.266,3.659c-.347,1.672-.679,3.347-1.045,5.015a1.393,1.393,0,0,1-2.12.7c-1.178-.946-2.326-1.925-3.5-2.872a5.373,5.373,0,0,1-3.316,1.44,5.365,5.365,0,0,1-3.882-1.4c-.844.621-1.628,1.367-2.453,2.033a6.315,6.315,0,0,1-1.2.924,1.393,1.393,0,0,1-1.839-.9c-.377-1.631-.771-3.257-1.136-4.89a3.96,3.96,0,0,1,1.335-3.81c.641-.517,1.29-1.025,1.943-1.527.182-.092.091-.3.1-.46a17.915,17.915,0,0,1,3.326-10.806m1.156,5.049a2.748,2.748,0,0,0,.24,3.641,3.024,3.024,0,0,0,4.134.085,2.75,2.75,0,0,0,.729-3.021,2.924,2.924,0,0,0-2.454-1.825,2.984,2.984,0,0,0-2.65,1.119"
                transform="translate(-251.1 457.654)"
                fill="#764abc"
              />
              <path
                id="Path_122"
                data-name="Path 122"
                d="M260.3-419.746a.693.693,0,0,1,1.027-.557,6.628,6.628,0,0,0,5.77,0,.7.7,0,0,1,1.029.516q.008,1.532,0,3.064a.691.691,0,0,1-1.079.5c-.306-.26-.582-.552-.876-.825-.467.874-.905,1.76-1.375,2.631a.7.7,0,0,1-1.161.007c-.472-.873-.908-1.764-1.384-2.637-.29.275-.566.566-.873.825a.692.692,0,0,1-1.078-.506c-.008-1.007,0-2.015,0-3.022"
                transform="translate(-253.92 446.225)"
                fill="#764abc"
              />
              <path
                id="Path_123"
                data-name="Path 123"
                d="M265.28-441.9a1.4,1.4,0,0,0,1.432-1.376,1.4,1.4,0,0,0-1.432-1.377,1.4,1.4,0,0,0-1.431,1.377,1.4,1.4,0,0,0,1.431,1.376"
                transform="translate(-255.01 453.668)"
                fill="#764abc"
              />
              <path
                id="Path_124"
                data-name="Path 124"
                d="M288.561-448.233H290.8v15.127h9.357v2.036h-11.6Zm13.563,11.211a5.99,5.99,0,0,1,.546-2.557,6.4,6.4,0,0,1,1.479-2.037,6.769,6.769,0,0,1,4.751-1.818,6.592,6.592,0,0,1,4.666,1.733,5.891,5.891,0,0,1,1.891,4.521,5.9,5.9,0,0,1-2.024,4.544,6.767,6.767,0,0,1-4.751,1.807A6.582,6.582,0,0,1,304-432.549a5.832,5.832,0,0,1-1.879-4.472m2.3-.133a4.517,4.517,0,0,0,.339,1.757A4.36,4.36,0,0,0,305.7-434a4.381,4.381,0,0,0,3.2,1.235,4.1,4.1,0,0,0,3.03-1.235,4.107,4.107,0,0,0,1.224-3.043,4.325,4.325,0,0,0-1.273-3.188,4.335,4.335,0,0,0-3.2-1.26,4.074,4.074,0,0,0-3.03,1.249,4.213,4.213,0,0,0-1.224,3.091m16.677,1.078a2.077,2.077,0,0,0-.582,1.3.918.918,0,0,0,.413.849,3.845,3.845,0,0,0,1.1.413q.692.157,1.564.266t1.794.218q.909.121,1.782.315a6.957,6.957,0,0,1,1.575.509,2.345,2.345,0,0,1,1.516,2.158,4.306,4.306,0,0,1-1.9,3.563,6.821,6.821,0,0,1-4.157,1.321,7.745,7.745,0,0,1-3.806-.873,3.147,3.147,0,0,1-1.831-2.861,3.762,3.762,0,0,1,.9-2.315,5.143,5.143,0,0,1,.558-.606,2.3,2.3,0,0,1-1.758-2.17,4.315,4.315,0,0,1,1.6-3.321,3.385,3.385,0,0,1-.557-1.878,3.7,3.7,0,0,1,.424-1.806,4.118,4.118,0,0,1,1.152-1.321,5.62,5.62,0,0,1,3.5-1.115,5.436,5.436,0,0,1,3.466,1.115,4.661,4.661,0,0,1,2.5-1.043,6.619,6.619,0,0,1,.945-.072l-.1,1.879a6.307,6.307,0,0,0-2.218.569,3.709,3.709,0,0,1,.412,1.721,3.4,3.4,0,0,1-.436,1.7,4.025,4.025,0,0,1-1.14,1.31,5.554,5.554,0,0,1-3.405,1.091,5.887,5.887,0,0,1-3.309-.91m.582-4.253a2.143,2.143,0,0,0-.231,1.017,2.221,2.221,0,0,0,.231,1.031,2.275,2.275,0,0,0,.654.739,3.493,3.493,0,0,0,2.085.582,2.688,2.688,0,0,0,2.594-1.285,2.074,2.074,0,0,0,.231-1.006,2.135,2.135,0,0,0-.243-1.03,2.124,2.124,0,0,0-.642-.751,3.446,3.446,0,0,0-2.085-.594,2.682,2.682,0,0,0-2.594,1.3m.024,8.944a3.151,3.151,0,0,0-.837,2.194,1.783,1.783,0,0,0,1.2,1.611,4.619,4.619,0,0,0,1.975.473,7.943,7.943,0,0,0,1.6-.134,3.885,3.885,0,0,0,1.139-.4,1.942,1.942,0,0,0,1.176-1.769q0-1.079-2.085-1.443-.9-.157-2.194-.279t-1.975-.254m27.052-11.563a5.27,5.27,0,0,1-3.515,5.273l3.261,6.606H345.9l-2.945-5.976a16.725,16.725,0,0,1-2.509.182h-4.461v5.793h-2.241v-17.163h7.042a12.082,12.082,0,0,1,5.684,1.042,4.451,4.451,0,0,1,2.291,4.242m-8.012,4.048a8.338,8.338,0,0,0,4.024-.752,3.344,3.344,0,0,0,1.612-3.151q0-2.885-3.733-3.273a19.936,19.936,0,0,0-2.218-.121h-4.449v7.3Zm10.7,1.879a5.99,5.99,0,0,1,.546-2.557,6.4,6.4,0,0,1,1.479-2.037,6.77,6.77,0,0,1,4.751-1.818A6.591,6.591,0,0,1,362.9-441.7a5.894,5.894,0,0,1,1.891,4.521,5.9,5.9,0,0,1-2.024,4.544,6.767,6.767,0,0,1-4.751,1.807,6.582,6.582,0,0,1-4.678-1.721,5.831,5.831,0,0,1-1.879-4.472m2.3-.133a4.517,4.517,0,0,0,.34,1.757,4.37,4.37,0,0,0,.933,1.394,4.383,4.383,0,0,0,3.2,1.235,4.1,4.1,0,0,0,3.03-1.235,4.107,4.107,0,0,0,1.224-3.043,4.325,4.325,0,0,0-1.273-3.188,4.336,4.336,0,0,0-3.2-1.26,4.073,4.073,0,0,0-3.03,1.249,4.214,4.214,0,0,0-1.224,3.091m23.344,3.491.424,1.709a7.408,7.408,0,0,1-4.46,1.127,5.729,5.729,0,0,1-4.412-1.721,6.409,6.409,0,0,1-1.563-4.557,6.234,6.234,0,0,1,1.757-4.509,5.974,5.974,0,0,1,4.448-1.818,6.431,6.431,0,0,1,3.9,1.1l-.8,1.805a5.411,5.411,0,0,0-3.321-1.017,3.3,3.3,0,0,0-2.7,1.284,4.622,4.622,0,0,0-.982,3.006,4.82,4.82,0,0,0,1.03,3.175,3.638,3.638,0,0,0,2.969,1.309,8.3,8.3,0,0,0,3.708-.9m3.066-16.326h2.3v12.133l5.442-5.333h2.69l-5.7,5.575,3.394,3.66a3.824,3.824,0,0,0,2.569,1.249l-.352,1.636a3.724,3.724,0,0,1-2.981-.678,6.8,6.8,0,0,1-.691-.667l-4.375-4.728v6.073h-2.3Zm22.108,7.866a4.441,4.441,0,0,1,1.006,1.624,5.626,5.626,0,0,1,.376,2.049,15.688,15.688,0,0,1-.243,2.533h-8.436a4.022,4.022,0,0,0,1.188,2.315,3.741,3.741,0,0,0,2.606.836,10.169,10.169,0,0,0,4.133-.824l.388,1.733a8.96,8.96,0,0,1-3.564.958,15.618,15.618,0,0,1-1.672.073,6.288,6.288,0,0,1-2.158-.412,4.692,4.692,0,0,1-1.866-1.212,6.631,6.631,0,0,1-1.466-4.654,6.234,6.234,0,0,1,1.757-4.509,5.974,5.974,0,0,1,4.448-1.818,4.733,4.733,0,0,1,3.5,1.309m-.812,4.425.049-.655a2.885,2.885,0,0,0-1.66-2.945,3.332,3.332,0,0,0-1.334-.242,3.368,3.368,0,0,0-1.43.3,3.514,3.514,0,0,0-1.114.825,4.376,4.376,0,0,0-1.091,2.715Zm5.358-3.624h-1.3v-1.5l2.982-2.242h.618v1.879h3.466v1.866h-3.466v4.9a5.311,5.311,0,0,0,.521,2.812,2.747,2.747,0,0,0,2.036.91l-.351,1.636q-3.636.46-4.3-2.873a10.568,10.568,0,0,1-.206-2.144Z"
                transform="translate(-262.589 455.303)"
                fill="#764abc"
              />
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </a>
    </div>
  
    <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        id="menu-button"
        class="h-6 w-6 cursor-pointer md:hidden block"
        fill="none"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        stroke="currentColor"
      >
        <path
          stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-linejoin="round"
          stroke-width="2"
          d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
        />
      </svg>
  
  <div class="navbar-show hidden w-full md:flex md:items-center md:w-auto" id="menu" x-show="open" @click.away="open = false">
      <ul
        class="
          text-xs text-gray-700
          md:flex
          md:justify-between 
          md:pt-0"
      >
        <li>
          <a class="inline-block py-2 px-4 text-white no-underline" href="#">
          <i class='selected-icon-color fill-current text-sm z-10 fas fa-user'></i> LOBBY</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="inline-block text-gray-400 no-underline hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-underline py-2 px-4" href="#"><i class="text-sm fas fa-users"></i> AUDITORIUM</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="inline-block text-gray-400 no-underline hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-underline py-2 px-4" href="#"><i class="text-sm fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> NETWORKING</a>
        </li>
        <li class="flex md:flex-none" id="ex2">
                    <a class="inline-block text-gray-400 no-underline hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-underline py-2 px-4" href="#"><i class="text-sm fas fa-comment-dots"></i> <span class="fa-stack" data-count="5">CHAT</span></a>
                </li>
        <li>
          <a class="inline-block text-gray-400 no-underline hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-underline py-2 px-4" href="#"><i class="text-sm fas fa-briefcase"></i> PERKS</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="inline-block text-gray-400 no-underline hover:text-gray-200 hover:text-underline py-2 px-4" href="#"><i class="text-sm fas fa-bell"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="relative inline-block">
              <div x-data="{ open: false }" class="relative">

                  <button @click="open = true" class="login-button flex items-center p-2 bg-white bg-gray-100 rounded-md"> <span class="pr-2"><img class="inline-block h-6 w-6 rounded-full ring-1 ring-white"
          src="./assets/images/avatar.avif"></span></span> Magda Lena <svg class="h-3 fill-current inline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                      <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z" /></svg>
                  </button>

                  <div x-show="open" @click.away="open = false" class="login-dropdown absolute right-0 py-2 mt-1 bg-gray-900 bg-gray-100 rounded-md shadow-xl w-34">
                      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-white-700 hover:bg-gray-400 hover:text-white">
                          Profile
                      </a>
                      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-white-700 hover:bg-gray-400 hover:text-white">
                          Settings
                      </a>
                      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-white-700 hover:bg-gray-400 hover:text-white">
                          Log Out
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you check the source code in your question? It seems like the first half is missing.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are trying to use the same state variable `open` to show the main menu modal and secondly to show a dropdown menu at the profile. However you define the `open` variable only at the dropdown menu, I do not see it at the nav element. I recommend to use different state variables for the two different functions. For the dropdown e.g.

```
<div class="relative inline-block">
   <div x-data="{ dropdownOpen: false }" class="relative">
     <button @click="dropdownOpen = true">...</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

And create an `open` variable at the navbar:

```
<nav x-data="{open: false}">
  ...
</nav>
```

This way clicking away should close both menus.